# Google Places API with HDAugmentedReality framework

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, google-places

I am using the Google Places API with the HDAugmented Reality Framework based off of this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/146436/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based-2) by Jean-Pierre.

My question is can you limit the search results (annotations) to only specific Places that fall under a criteria.

> Ex: On a University campus limiting annotations to only University buildings.

Google Places offers an option called Autocomplete but I am not sure how to incorporate it into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your url to match the parameters you intend to display.

Visit https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete for examples and lists of parameters.